# выдает invalid syntax при условии, что я хочу присвоить params значение которое вернет функция make_parameters()

Tags: python, requests

строчка ошибки 30

```
import requests


cities = [
'Омск',
'Калининград',
'Челябинск',
'Владивосток',
'Красноярск',
'Москва',
'Екатеринбург'
]


def make_url(city):

    return f'http://wttr.in/{city}'


def make_parameters():
    params = {
        'format': 2,  
    'M': ''  
}
    return params


def what_weather(city):
    try:
            return requests.get(make_url(city)), params = make_parameters()
    except requests.ConnectionError:
            return '<сетевая ошибка>'
    except if make_url(city)==200 and requests.ConnectionError:
            return '<ошибка на сервере погоды>'
  
print('Погода в городах:')
for city in cities:
    print(city, what_weather(city))
```

Comment: Ваша функция make_parameters ничего не возвращает, а return не может стоять за пределами функции

Comment: окей, я просто неправильно ввел код на сайт

Comment: А в строке `return requests.get(make_url(city)), params = make_parameters()` вы попытались написать какое-то странное присваивание после вызова функции requests.get

Comment: Да, PEP8 вы нарушаете в хвост и в гриву. И кстати, где тут 30 строка?

Answer (score 2):

Вы тут немного со скобками не попали)
`return requests.get(make_url(city), params = make_parameters())`
Вот так по идее будет правильнее, это что касается присваивания.
Хотя все равно в блоках except у вас ошибка.